# how do i set hard and soft file limits for a non-root user at boot?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, limits

I have a xen HVM vps and I'm trying to raise the hard and soft file limits for nobody at boot time. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.3 and inside /etc/security/limits.conf I have:

```
nobody       soft    nofile   10000
nobody       hard    nofile  30000
```

But when I check the file limits are still the default 1024:

```
su nobody -c 'ulimit -Hn'
1024
su nobody -c 'ulimit -Sn'
1024
```

What is the right way of raising the file limits for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

/etc/security/limits.conf file is processed by the `pam_limits` PAM module and is used to assign resource limits for a user session. These will be applied only when PAM and the `pam_limits` module is used during the session setup.

In your system the `su` utility may be not configured to use the `pam_limits` module (see the `/etc/pam.d/su.conf` file)  or uses it only when creating a new login session (called with a `-`, `-l` or `--login` option).

Try using

```
su - nobody -c 'ulimit -Hn'
```

or adding

```
session     required    pam_limits.so
```

To `/etc/pam.d/su` or/and `/etc/pam.d/su-l`.

It may also be the case, that your `su` utility is not compiled with PAM support at all. In such case it will never use the `limits.conf` file.

Comment: I tried using su - nobody -c 'ulimit -Hn' but it says 1024. What does this mean for the user nobody and nginx? That there aren't really any file limits and this tweak isn't necessary?

Comment: I ran into a similar problem when trying to run a service (JBoss) on Ubuntu 10.04 as a non-root user and getting lots of "too many open files" exceptions. I had already increased the nofiles limit which was verified with a normal login shell but it was not taking effect for any services started as a non-root user via su in an init script. I found that "su --login" still didn't pick up the increased nofiles limit even though pam_limits was uncommented in /etc/pam.d/login. I had to uncomment the pam_limits line in /etc/pam.d/su before it worked. It seems to me that /etc/pam.d/su applies to "su -